# Can a teenager travel on an adult ticket for a Ryanair flight?

Tags: ryanair

I had booked Belfast - London flights for myself and my son. A few weeks later my 14 year old daughter decided to come, so I set about booking her a ticket online.  However it is not possible to book a teen by themselves, so the website advises to book them as an adult, then contact Customer Services and link her to our booking.

Today I tried to do this, but the very (very) rude person on the phone told me it would cost me £30 to change her from an adult ticket to a teen ticket (even though there is no price difference in the fares).

I'm wondering could we just wing it, say nothing and hope they don't notice she is traveling with on an adult ticket instead of a teen ticket? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your daughter travelling with you and your son, there and back? I asking this in case she's travelling alone and might be considered an Unaccompanied Minor.

Comment: @canonacer Ryanair do not carry unaccompanied minors.

Comment: @MJeffryes Yes, that's just repeating the statement in the question that you can't book a teenager without an adult travelling with them.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sure, which is why I'm confused about what clarification canonacer is seeking.

Comment: I was asking if the daughter was doing either leg of the journey alone. Even with an adult ticket Ryanair would consider her an UnMin. Even though some people that age are very worldly wise and well traveled.

Answer (score 3):

You ask whether you could "wing it" and just hope for the best, but surely £30 isn't much to pay compared to the risk of an over-officious member of staff at the gate refusing to allow you to fly?

Having to pay to change her ticket does indeed seem very unfair, but sadly Ryanair aren't known for bending over backwards to help customers and this looks like yet another sneaky way in which they try to squeeze as much money as possible out of customers by charging for anything they can get away with.

So yes, I don't blame you for resenting paying the extra £30. But at the end of the day, there's always a chance you'll all be denied boarding (or that your daughter will be denied boarding which presumably means you'll all be stuck at the airport), and for the sake of £30 this feels like too much of a risk to me.

(Or for the cost of another phone call, you could trying calling again and hope that you get a more sympathetic agent..)